# With an application server behind a reverse proxy, which server should handle the error pages and why?

Tags: reverse-proxy, application-server, errordocument, custom-errors

We have a reverse proxy setup for our application that is managed by another team.  Currently the 404 and 403 pages we've setup on the application server are overwritten with the reverse proxy error pages.

Is there way to let the application server handle this? Is there any reason why it would be advisable to let the reverse proxy do this?

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on your requirements and the proxy

For example [NGINX](http://wwww.nginx.org) can intercept errors for you and then do a X. This might allow you to serve cached content even if the application server was down (depending on your application). You might want to send users to a different url, if they get a certain error.

It also allows you to make error pages accessible even if the application was down. Maintain the content of those error pages is simpler because they can be maintained on the proxy rather then spread over different backends (think about as you expand the application)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the proxy server handle the error pages, you have the ability to offer a consistent message to the client, no matter what site the error is generated for.

Also, in the event of a backend server failure, the backend server will not be accessible and therefore unable to produce the custom error pages.

Third, you only need to keep one set of custom error pages updated, rather than going to each individual server and making sure the pages are current.